# How do I add subviews to a custom UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a custom UICollectionViewCell class where I want to add subviews.

My cell class: The SetUpView() method will add all the subvies I need.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RecipeCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var RecipeImg: UIImage!
    var StarRatingImg: UIImage!
    var RecipeTitleText = ""
    var RecipeTextDescription = ""


    var View: UIView!
    var ImageContainer: UIImageView!
    var FavIcon: UIImageView!
    var StarRatingContainer: UIImageView!
    var KCAL: UILabel!
    var RecipeTitle: UITextView!
    var RecipeText: UITextView!


    func SetUpView()
    {
        //DropDown!.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

        //View for recipe
        View = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.width, self.frame.height))
        View.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

        //Recipe image
        ImageContainer = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, View.frame.width, View.frame.height/2))
        ImageContainer.image = RecipeImg
        ImageContainer.contentMode = .ScaleToFill

        //Recipe favorit icon
        FavIcon = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(ImageContainer.frame.width - 35, 5, 30, 30))
        FavIcon.image = UIImage(named: "LikeHeart")

        //Star rating image
        StarRatingContainer = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(10, ImageContainer.frame.height + 5, ImageContainer.frame.width - 20, (View.frame.height/2) * (1/5)))
        StarRatingContainer.image = StarRatingImg
        StarRatingContainer.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit

        //RecipeTitle container
        RecipeTitle = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(10, StarRatingContainer.frame.height + ImageContainer.frame.height + 10, View.frame.width - 20, 30))
        RecipeTitle.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Semibold", size: 12)
        //RecipeTitle.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        RecipeTitle.editable = false
        RecipeTitle.text = RecipeTitleText
        RecipeTitle.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)


        //RecipeText container
        RecipeText = UITextView(frame: CGRectMake(10, StarRatingContainer.frame.height + ImageContainer.frame.height + RecipeTitle.frame.height + 15, View.frame.width - 20, 50))
        RecipeText.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 12)
        //RecipeText.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        RecipeText.editable = false
        RecipeText.text = RecipeTextDescription
        RecipeText.textContainerInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, 0, 0)

        //KCAL label
        KCAL = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(15, StarRatingContainer.frame.height + ImageContainer.frame.height + RecipeTitle.frame.height + RecipeText.frame.height + 20, 200, 20))
        KCAL.text = "420 KCAL. PER. PORTION"
        KCAL.font = UIFont(name: "OpenSans-Bold", size: 10)
        KCAL.textColor = UIColor(CGColor: "#dc994a".CGColor)

        //Adding the views
        self.addSubview(View)
        View.addSubview(ImageContainer)
        View.addSubview(KCAL)
        View.addSubview(StarRatingContainer)
        View.addSubview(RecipeTitle)
        View.addSubview(RecipeText)
        ImageContainer.addSubview(FavIcon)

        View.bringSubviewToFront(ImageContainer)

    }

}
```

I have a UICollectionView which uses the custom cell class.

I create my UICollectionView in viewDidLoad()

```
// Create Collection view
        layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: screenWidth/MenuViewConst  - 1, height: screenWidth - 1)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 1
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 1

        collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 105, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height - 150), collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView?.tag = 5
        collectionView!.dataSource = self
        collectionView!.delegate = self
        collectionView!.registerClass(RecipeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
        collectionView!.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGrayColor()
        collectionView!.contentInset.top = 0
```

In cellForItemAtIndexPath delegate I set up the UICollectionView to use my custom cell class. But I can't call the SetUpView() method from my custom cell class here, because that will just keep adding subviews on subviews. I can't figure out how to add the subviews to the UICollectionViewCell before entering the delegate. Hope you guys can help - Thank you

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

        let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RecipeCell

        let recipe = self.RecipeArr[indexPath.row]

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.grayColor()
        cell.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        cell.layer.borderWidth = 0.5
        cell.RecipeImg = UIImage(named: "Burger")
        cell.StarRatingImg = UIImage(named: "StarRating")
        cell.RecipeTitleText = recipe["name"].string!
        cell.RecipeTextDescription = recipe["instruction"].string!

        //BAD IDEA!
        //cell.SetUpView()

        print("new cell")

        return cell

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `init(frame: CGRect)` inherited function in the `UICollectionViewCell` .

```
class RecipeCell: UICollectionViewCell {
   var imageView : UIImageView?
   override init(frame: CGRect) {
     super.init(frame: frame)
     //initialize all your subviews.
     imageView = UIImageView()
   }
}
```

also don't forget to register your custom class in the `viewDidLoad` function

```
collectionView!.registerClass(RecipeCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionViewCell")
```

and your collectionview delegate would be like this

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell  = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CollectionViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RecipeCell
    cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named:"yourImage.png")
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respons @zumrymohamed. I tried that (initwithframe), but the properties does not get set in cellForItemAtIndexPath. ex: cell.RecipeImg = UIImage(named: "Burger") and the properties below don't get set.

Comment: Check the edited answer properly. you should initialize your imageview in "init" method.